# how to fill series in excel for cell which are non identical in size?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have list of test cases with each test cases having diff number of steps. I want to use the Fill Series option for Test Case ID column (which is merged cell). How to fill the series for those merged cell? I am new to this, so please answer accordingly.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Merged cells should be avoided, since they create roadblocks for all kinds of functionality, for example filling data down or across.

Instead of merging cells across columns, use "Center across selection" in the Alignments tab of the format dialog.

Or don't merge at all and create the visual appearance of cells by formatting borders and backgrounds.

With these two approaches you will not run into any problems when selecting cells or filling data.